# jQuery select all classes except one ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to select all divs of a certain class (jqx-slider) excluding one  ID (#str_prg) - something like:

```
$("div.jqx-slider :not(#str_prg)").each(function () {
.....
});
```

What is the correct syntax for that?

Also, would it be faster and more effecient code, if I add a "if" condition inside the loop - like

```
if($(this).attr('id') ! = "str_prg"){

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: the documentation for .not is pretty clear... https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using an descendant selector between the class selector and the not selector, which is invalid for your requirement

```
$("div.jqx-slider:not(#str_prg)")
```

when you say `$("div.jqx-slider :not(#str_prg)")` it selects all descendants of elements with class `jq-slider` except the one with id `str_prg`

Comment: Thanks. Would it be faster to add If condition inside the loop to deselect certain IDs?

Comment: it could be if it is a very simple condition, but unless you are dealing with 100s of elements it may not make any considerable difference....

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove an unnecessary space char like this:

```
$("div.jqx-slider:not(#str_prg)")
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the space, as it would cause you to select children, instead of the element itself.

```
$("div.jqx-slider:not(#str_prg)").each(function() {
    .....
});
```

For the second part of your question, it would be better to just use the CSS selector instead of a JS loop.